# How can I combine this query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel Eloquent to hit the database twice. I merge the results of the 2 queries into one. How can I make this into a single query so it only hits the database once?

```
$openers = Comments::select('id', 'parent_id', 'opener_id', 'topic', 'username', 'comment', 'upvotes', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at')
    ->where('topic', '=', $topic)
    ->where('parent_id', '=', 0)
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

$replies = Comments::select('id', 'parent_id', 'opener_id', 'topic', 'username', 'comment', 'upvotes', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at')
    ->where('topic', '=', $topic)
    ->where('parent_id', '!=', 0)
    ->orderBy('parent_id')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();

$comments = $openers->merge($replies);
```

Basically I'd like the rows with parent_id: 0 to be sorted by id and the rows where the parent_id is not 0 to be sorted by parent_id but NOT by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove condition (parent_id = 0 ,parent_id != 0 ) and add conditional order by to sort all comments first and then all replies, Another conditional order by to sort comments by id and replies by parent_id

```
$results = Comments::select(
    'id', 'parent_id', 'opener_id', 'topic', 'username', 'comment', 'upvotes', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at',
    DB::raw("CASE WHEN parent_id = 0 THEN 'Comments' ELSE 'Replies' END as comment_type")
)
    ->where('topic', '=', $topic)
    ->orderByRaw('parent_id = 0 DESC')
    ->orderByRaw('CASE WHEN parent_id = 0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END ASC')
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know your figuring out something else, cause in basic query you can actually obtain your issue already.

[Sample query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xFLw.jpg)

or if you want to do some complex query but your having issue on how to do it via ORM method. You can create a trick the Model by creating a "VIEW" table in your database and then do the complex query in that VIEW with the same columns on your table or adding/remove column too! :)

you can do something like this,

in your SQL database

```
CREATE VIEW `sample_database`.`view_comment` AS 
SELECT *, (SELECT some_field FROM other_table) as extra_field FROM comment
WHERE (some_field = 'SOME_CONDITION_ONLY') AND
some_date BETWEEN 'FROM_DATE' AND 'END_DATE'
```

then in your Php laravel code, you can create a 'ViewComment' model, then you can do a query something like this still.

```
ViewComment::where('some_field','YOUR_CONDITION')->get(); //or
ViewComment::paginate(10);
```